# Cloning a topic in kafka without losing original timestamps

Tags: apache-kafka

Have a requirement , want to clone the kafka topic so that original timestamp of messages are not lost. Cloning of the topic within same cluster.

What are the possible options available for me to achieve it ?

Context: Designing an application and testing some scenarios. Assume its a banking application . For audit i want the original messages timestamps to be preserved.

Tried kafkacat but it doesnt preserve timestamps

```
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -C -t testmytopic -K: -e -o beginning | \kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -P -t testmytarget -K:
% Reached end of topic testmytopic [0] at offset 4: exiting

kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testmytopic --property print.timestamp=true --from-beginning
CreateTime:1617271441751    test1
CreateTime:1617271441762    test2
CreateTime:1617271441762    test3
CreateTime:1617271444505    
^CProcessed a total of 4 messages

kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testmytarget --property print.timestamp=true --from-beginning
CreateTime:1617271539027    test1
CreateTime:1617271539027    test2
CreateTime:1617271539027    test3
CreateTime:1617271539027
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain the context for wanting to do this? Is it a DR design? An application? etc.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt done

Comment: Have you tried MirrorMaker or Replicator? Do those not do what you want?

Comment: MirrorMaker works only if its a different cluster - am i right ?